# Adding 2D text on plane geometry three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created plane geometry and textured 2D text on plane geometry but I am unable to fit the text on plane
geometry properly and I need to set the width and height of plane geometry according to the size of text
can someone please help me how to do this. I have also uploaded code and image.

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
for(var i=0; i<spriteResponse.length; i++)
{   


    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    metrics = null,
    textHeight = 100,
    textWidth = 0,
    actualFontSize = 2;
    context.font = "normal " + textHeight + "px Arial";
    metrics = context.measureText(cardinal.name);
    var textWidth = metrics.width;
    canvas.width = textWidth;
    canvas.height = textHeight;
    context.font = "normal " + textHeight + "px Arial";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.textBaseline = "middle";
    context.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
    context.fillText(cardinal.name, textWidth / 2, textHeight / 2);


    var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas) ;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    //var spriteAlignment = new THREE.Vector2(0,0) ;
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffffff, side: THREE.DoubleSide ,map : texture} );
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 0.5, 0.3);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    plane.position.set(X_value,0,Z_value);

    scene.add(plane);
    var direction = camera.getWorldDirection();
    plane.lookAt(direction);
}
```

Comment: @PradipShenolkar I didn't get you

Comment: Sorry for that. When I tried earlier due to some reason image was not getting displayed. May be due to server issue.